# Positioning a div relative to its parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to put shade over the top of an image to make the image darker, only issue is I can't seem to position the shade class over the top of the image, I can't seem to start it in the top left corner of the image, instead it starts at the top left corner of the entire screen.

```css
.pic {
  .shade-container {
    grid-area: pic;
    border: 2px green solid;
    }
  img {
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .shade {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
  <section class="pic">
    <div class="shade-container">
      <img src="images/self.jpg" alt="Picture of me">
      <div class="shade"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Freelance Java Developer</p>
    <p><a href="https://github.com/Realmm">Portfolio</a></p>
  </section>
```

The result:

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 2):

You would have a div containing the `position: absolute` div that has `position: relative`

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.inside {
    position: absolute;
}
```

The div with the class 'inside' will be positioned relative to the wrapper div.

In your case, you would also use

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Properties inside the 'inside' div in order to cover it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the all classes properties to main section pic class like this below no need to use like this its a wrong method.

```
.pic {
 .shade-container {
  grid-area: pic;
  border: 2px green solid;
  }
  img {
   z-index: -1;
   width: 100vw;
  }
  .shade {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
}
```

This is a right method.

```
.pic {
 }
.shade-container {
  grid-area: pic;
  border: 2px green solid;
  position: relative;
 }
 img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100vw;
 }
 .shade {
   background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) );
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  }
```

```css
.pic {
}
  .shade-container {
    grid-area: pic;
    border: 2px green solid;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    }
  img {
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .shade {
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) );
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

```html
 <section class="pic">
    <div class="shade-container">
      <img src="images/self.jpg" alt="Picture of me">
      <div class="shade"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Freelance Java Developer</p>
    <p><a href="https://github.com/Realmm">Portfolio</a></p>
  </section>
```